# Trying to render my app component., but I am unable to do so as it unable to find App

Tags: reactjs, react-18

I am using React 18 and very new to it, I get the following error
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

src\index.js
Line 5:14:  'App' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Following is my code and necessary screenshot
index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(<App />);
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';

import { About, Footer, Header, Skills, Testimonial, Work } from './container';
import { Navbar } from './components';
import './App.scss';

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <Navbar />
    <Header />
    <About />
    <Work />
    <Skills />
    <Testimonial />
    <Footer />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Following is my file structure
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2n4P.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Update: I have done that, and I thought I was missing that. But I get hit with more error in the Console, regarding the App

Following is the screenshot
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFKRn.png)

Comment: index.js needs `import App from './App'`

Comment: You are missing this import in your index.js `import App from './App'`

Comment: I have done that, but run into bunch of other errors regarding ./App have added updates

Comment: ONe of your component's doesn't return proper jsx. Probably `Work`